# SLF4J multiple bindings Spring boot with weblogic

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, logback, slf4j, logback-classic

I updated my spring boot application version to 5.3.24, and I excluded the logback from all dependencies, I checked it with dependency:tree

```
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.25:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.27:provided
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.27:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.27:provided
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.3.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.5.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.13.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.1.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.3:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.transaction:jakarta.transaction-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.8.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.24.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.29:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.29:compile
[INFO] +- com.lmax:disruptor:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle.ojdbc:ojdbc8:jar:19.3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.ojdbc:ucp:jar:19.3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.ojdbc:oraclepki:jar:19.3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.ojdbc:osdt_cert:jar:19.3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.ojdbc:osdt_core:jar:19.3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.oracle.ojdbc:simplefan:jar:19.3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.oracle.ojdbc:ons:jar:19.3.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.12:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:18.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.mapstruct:mapstruct:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.cccis.framework:bamlogger-weblogic:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.jms:javax.jms-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.cccis.common:common-objects:jar:0.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.6:compile
[INFO] +- com.cccis.framework:framework-dataobjects:jar:10.3.189:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.cccis.framework:framework-core:jar:10.3.189:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- axis:axis:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.cccis.servicepower:sp-client:jar:2.12.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.cccis.stdvehicle:vinservice-common:jar:0.0.23:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.cccis.framework:simple-storage:jar:0.0.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.uuid:java-uuid-generator:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet.ext.httpclient:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:jar:4.5.10:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- net.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.apache.james:apache-mime4j-core:jar:0.7.2:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.restlet.jee:org.restlet:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.ext.json:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.restlet.jse:org.restlet.lib.org.json:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.restlet.jse:org.restlet:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.10.50:compile
[INFO] |        +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.10.50:compile
[INFO] |        \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.10.50:compile
[INFO] |           \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.5:compile
[INFO] \- com.cccis.frm.journal:journal-logger:jar:5.0.16:compile
[INFO]    \- com.cccis.frm.journal:ejb_journal_client:jar:5.0.16:compile
[INFO]       \- com.cccis.framework:framework-interfaces:jar:10.3.49:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But After I rebuild my appliation I got the SLF4J multiple bindings and with logback

[ERROR] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/gtth/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.0.13/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/gtth/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.12.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

I did everything, shall the Spring be bugged? :(

What can i do?

Comment: One of your dependencies might include Logback classes. Can you add your Maven dependencies to your question? BTW: see the [Log4j2 Security page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html) and upgrade to a version without vulnerabilities.